# increment node value dynamically

Tags: xslt

I have an input xml which has the following structure,

```
<VEN>
<CUS>
    <MEM>
    <MEM>
    <MEM>
</CUS>
<CUS>
    <MEM>
    <MEM>
    <MEM>
</CUS>
```

each node occurs multiple times in input xml. There is an attribute @CLM01 in every MEM
node which has to be assigned a value depending upon every 20 occurences of MEM nodes. Starting from the first VEN/CUS, if there are 55 nodes of MEM then first 20 nodes will have @CLM01 value of '1' and for same VEN/CUS combination the next 20 nodes will have value '2' and remaining 15 nodes will have @CLM01 value '3'.

And for the next CUS(assuming this CUS has 30 MEM nodes) under the Same VEN the first twenty MEM nodes will have @CLM01 value of '4' and next ten MEM will have @CLM01 with value '5'. This goes on..... I hope i am clear what i am trying to achieve.

Thanks. is it possible? using xslt 1.0

Here is the sample input

```
<Data>
<VEN vendorId= "v1">
    <CUS custId = "c1">
        <MEM memId="m1" CLM01=""/>
        <MEM memId="m2" CLM01=""/>
        <MEM memId="m3" CLM01=""/>
        <MEM memId="m4" CLM01=""/>
        <MEM memId="m5" CLM01=""/>
    </CUS>
    <CUS custId = "c2">
        <MEM memId="m11" CLM01=""/>
        <MEM memId="m12" CLM01=""/>
        <MEM memId="m13" CLM01=""/>
        <MEM memId="m14" CLM01=""/>
        <MEM memId="m15" CLM01=""/>
        <MEM memId="m16" CLM01=""/>
        <MEM memId="m17" CLM01=""/>
        <MEM memId="m18" CLM01=""/>
    </CUS>
</VEN>
<VEN vendorId= "v2">
    <CUS custId = "c1">
        <MEM memId="m4" CLM01=""/>
        <MEM memId="m5" CLM01=""/>
        <MEM memId="m6" CLM01=""/>
        <MEM memId="m7" CLM01=""/>
        <MEM memId="m8" CLM01=""/>
    </CUS>
    <CUS custId = "c1">
        <MEM memId="m33" CLM01=""/>
        <MEM memId="m44" CLM01=""/>
        <MEM memId="m55" CLM01=""/>
        <MEM memId="m66" CLM01=""/>
        <MEM memId="m77" CLM01=""/>
        <MEM memId="m88" CLM01=""/>
        <MEM memId="m99" CLM01=""/>
        <MEM memId="m11" CLM01=""/>
    </CUS>
</VEN>
```

The Desired output (instead of 20 occurences of MEM nodes we go for every 3 occurences)

```
<Data>
<VEN vendorId= "v1">
    <CUS custId = "c1">
        <MEM memId="m1" CLM01="1"/>
        <MEM memId="m2" CLM01="1"/>
        <MEM memId="m3" CLM01="1"/>
        <MEM memId="m4" CLM01="2"/>
        <MEM memId="m5" CLM01="2"/>
    </CUS>
    <CUS custId = "c2">
        <MEM memId="m11" CLM01="3"/>
        <MEM memId="m12" CLM01="3"/>
        <MEM memId="m13" CLM01="3"/>
        <MEM memId="m14" CLM01="4"/>
        <MEM memId="m15" CLM01="4"/>
        <MEM memId="m16" CLM01="4"/>
        <MEM memId="m17" CLM01="5"/>
        <MEM memId="m18" CLM01="5"/>
    </CUS>
</VEN>
<VEN vendorId= "v2">
    <CUS custId = "c1">
        <MEM memId="m4" CLM01="6"/>
        <MEM memId="m5" CLM01="6"/>
        <MEM memId="m6" CLM01="6"/>
        <MEM memId="m7" CLM01="7"/>
        <MEM memId="m8" CLM01="7"/>
    </CUS>
    <CUS custId = "c1">
        <MEM memId="m33" CLM01="8"/>
        <MEM memId="m44" CLM01="8"/>
        <MEM memId="m55" CLM01="8"/>
        <MEM memId="m66" CLM01="9"/>
        <MEM memId="m77" CLM01="9"/>
        <MEM memId="m88" CLM01="9"/>
        <MEM memId="m99" CLM01="10"/>
        <MEM memId="m11" CLM01="10"/>
    </CUS>
</VEN>
```

Comment: Why don't you provide well-formed input that has the actual structure? And the output you want to produce? Makes it easier for people to figure out what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Michael: yes, you are correct. I guess this would help. Thanks. I am using xsl:number storing in variable but i dont know how to achieve condition for incrementing value after every 3 nodes of MEM.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pSize" select="3"/>


 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="vrtfPass1">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="vPass2" select=
   "ext:node-set($vrtfPass1)"/>

   <xsl:apply-templates select="$vPass2/*" mode="pass2"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "MEM[not(following-sibling::MEM)]">
   <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>

   <xsl:variable name="vPos" select=
   "count(preceding-sibling::MEM)+1"/>

   <xsl:variable name="pTimes"
        select="$pSize - ($vPos mod $pSize)"/>

   <xsl:call-template name="genMems">
    <xsl:with-param name="pTimes" select="$pTimes"/>
   </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="genMems">
  <xsl:param name="pTimes"/>

  <xsl:if test="$pTimes >0">
   <MEM fake="yes"/>

   <xsl:call-template name="genMems">
    <xsl:with-param name="pTimes" select="$pTimes -1"/>
   </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="pass2" name="identity2">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="pass2"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="MEM/@CLM01" mode="pass2">
  <xsl:attribute name="CLM01">
   <xsl:variable name="vNum">
    <xsl:number count="MEM" level="any"/>
   </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:value-of select=
      "ceiling($vNum div $pSize)"/>
   </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="MEM[@fake='yes']" mode="pass2"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Data>
    <VEN vendorId= "v1">
        <CUS custId = "c1">
            <MEM memId="m1" CLM01=""/>
            <MEM memId="m2" CLM01=""/>
            <MEM memId="m3" CLM01=""/>
            <MEM memId="m4" CLM01=""/>
            <MEM memId="m5" CLM01=""/>
        </CUS>
        <CUS custId = "c2">
            <MEM memId="m11" CLM01=""/>
            <MEM memId="m12" CLM01=""/>
            <MEM memId="m13" CLM01=""/>
            <MEM memId="m14" CLM01=""/>
            <MEM memId="m15" CLM01=""/>
            <MEM memId="m16" CLM01=""/>
            <MEM memId="m17" CLM01=""/>
            <MEM memId="m18" CLM01=""/>
        </CUS>
    </VEN>
    <VEN vendorId= "v2">
        <CUS custId = "c1">
            <MEM memId="m4" CLM01=""/>
            <MEM memId="m5" CLM01=""/>
            <MEM memId="m6" CLM01=""/>
            <MEM memId="m7" CLM01=""/>
            <MEM memId="m8" CLM01=""/>
        </CUS>
        <CUS custId = "c1">
            <MEM memId="m33" CLM01=""/>
            <MEM memId="m44" CLM01=""/>
            <MEM memId="m55" CLM01=""/>
            <MEM memId="m66" CLM01=""/>
            <MEM memId="m77" CLM01=""/>
            <MEM memId="m88" CLM01=""/>
            <MEM memId="m99" CLM01=""/>
            <MEM memId="m11" CLM01=""/>
        </CUS>
    </VEN>
</Data>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<Data>
   <VEN vendorId="v1">
      <CUS custId="c1">
         <MEM memId="m1" CLM01="1"/>
         <MEM memId="m2" CLM01="1"/>
         <MEM memId="m3" CLM01="1"/>
         <MEM memId="m4" CLM01="2"/>
         <MEM memId="m5" CLM01="2"/>
      </CUS>
      <CUS custId="c2">
         <MEM memId="m11" CLM01="3"/>
         <MEM memId="m12" CLM01="3"/>
         <MEM memId="m13" CLM01="3"/>
         <MEM memId="m14" CLM01="4"/>
         <MEM memId="m15" CLM01="4"/>
         <MEM memId="m16" CLM01="4"/>
         <MEM memId="m17" CLM01="5"/>
         <MEM memId="m18" CLM01="5"/>
      </CUS>
   </VEN>
   <VEN vendorId="v2">
      <CUS custId="c1">
         <MEM memId="m4" CLM01="6"/>
         <MEM memId="m5" CLM01="6"/>
         <MEM memId="m6" CLM01="6"/>
         <MEM memId="m7" CLM01="7"/>
         <MEM memId="m8" CLM01="7"/>
      </CUS>
      <CUS custId="c1">
         <MEM memId="m33" CLM01="8"/>
         <MEM memId="m44" CLM01="8"/>
         <MEM memId="m55" CLM01="8"/>
         <MEM memId="m66" CLM01="9"/>
         <MEM memId="m77" CLM01="9"/>
         <MEM memId="m88" CLM01="9"/>
         <MEM memId="m99" CLM01="10"/>
         <MEM memId="m11" CLM01="10"/>
      </CUS>
   </VEN>
</Data>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Two pass transformation.
2. The first pass adds fake `MEM` elements so that each `CUS` element in the result has `MEM` children whose number is a multiple of `$pSize`.
3. The second pass:
4. Using and overriding the **[identity rule](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)**.
5. Using **[`<xsl:number>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#number)** to get the correct numbering of `MEM` elements with `level="any"`.

Comment: +1. I'm really educating from each and every one of your posts. Thanks!

Comment: But the OP's example implied groups cannot cross `<CUS>` elements, so the first group in every `<CUS>` would always have the maximum number of members, provided, of course, that there are enough elements. I've given that some thought, but it appears difficult to solve.

Comment: @Michael-Ludwig: Good catch. I hadn't noticed this strange requirement. My answer is now updated to implement this requirement, too.

Comment: @Dimitre:   <xsl:variable name="vPass2" select="ext:node($vrtfPass1)"/> ----- Unable to perform XSL Transformation. 'Name and Number of arguments do not match any function signature in static context'. Sorry but i have seen this error for first time.

Comment: @bluesnowxyz: The `xxx:node-set()` function is XSLT processor-dependent. What XSLT processor are you using? For MSXML the namespace is: `"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"` . I use the EXSLT namespace in my answer, because EXSLT is implemented by the majority of XSLT processors.

Comment: @Dimitre: I am using Altova's built-in XSLT processor. It won't support?

Comment: @bluesnowxyz: I have never used Altova and it seems that their recent versions are XSLT 2.0, where there is no need to use the `xxx:node-set()` extension. Just try: `<xsl:variable name="vPass2" select="$vrtfPass1"/>`

Comment: @bluesnowxyz: Yes, I tried my suggestion from the previous comment and this works in AltovaXML.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, one pass transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:param name="pSize" select="3"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:param name="pOffset" select="0"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*">
                <xsl:with-param name="pOffset" select="$pOffset"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="pPosition" select="position()"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="VEN|CUS">
        <xsl:param name="pOffset" select="0"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vIsVEN" select="self::VEN"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates
             select="@*|node()[position()=1 and $vIsVEN or not($vIsVEN)]">
                <xsl:with-param name="pOffset" select="$pOffset"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]">
            <xsl:with-param name="pOffset"
             select="$pOffset + count(.//MEM[position() mod $pSize = 1])"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="MEM/@CLM01">
        <xsl:param name="pPosition" select="1"/>
        <xsl:param name="pOffset" select="0"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
            <xsl:value-of 
             select="$pOffset + ceiling(($pPosition - 1) div $pSize)"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<Data>
    <VEN vendorId="v1">
        <CUS custId="c1">
            <MEM memId="m1" CLM01="1"></MEM>
            <MEM memId="m2" CLM01="1"></MEM>
            <MEM memId="m3" CLM01="1"></MEM>
            <MEM memId="m4" CLM01="2"></MEM>
            <MEM memId="m5" CLM01="2"></MEM>
        </CUS>
        <CUS custId="c2">
            <MEM memId="m11" CLM01="3"></MEM>
            <MEM memId="m12" CLM01="3"></MEM>
            <MEM memId="m13" CLM01="3"></MEM>
            <MEM memId="m14" CLM01="4"></MEM>
            <MEM memId="m15" CLM01="4"></MEM>
            <MEM memId="m16" CLM01="4"></MEM>
            <MEM memId="m17" CLM01="5"></MEM>
            <MEM memId="m18" CLM01="5"></MEM>
        </CUS>
    </VEN>
    <VEN vendorId="v2">
        <CUS custId="c1">
            <MEM memId="m4" CLM01="6"></MEM>
            <MEM memId="m5" CLM01="6"></MEM>
            <MEM memId="m6" CLM01="6"></MEM>
            <MEM memId="m7" CLM01="7"></MEM>
            <MEM memId="m8" CLM01="7"></MEM>
        </CUS>
        <CUS custId="c1">
            <MEM memId="m33" CLM01="8"></MEM>
            <MEM memId="m44" CLM01="8"></MEM>
            <MEM memId="m55" CLM01="8"></MEM>
            <MEM memId="m66" CLM01="9"></MEM>
            <MEM memId="m77" CLM01="9"></MEM>
            <MEM memId="m88" CLM01="9"></MEM>
            <MEM memId="m99" CLM01="10"></MEM>
            <MEM memId="m11" CLM01="10"></MEM>
        </CUS>
    </VEN>
    <VEN vendorId="v2">
        <CUS custId="c1">
            <MEM memId="m4" CLM01="1"></MEM>
            <MEM memId="m5" CLM01="1"></MEM>
            <MEM memId="m6" CLM01="1"></MEM>
            <MEM memId="m7" CLM01="2"></MEM>
            <MEM memId="m8" CLM01="2"></MEM>
        </CUS>
        <CUS custId="c1">
            <MEM memId="m33" CLM01="3"></MEM>
            <MEM memId="m44" CLM01="3"></MEM>
            <MEM memId="m55" CLM01="3"></MEM>
            <MEM memId="m66" CLM01="4"></MEM>
            <MEM memId="m77" CLM01="4"></MEM>
            <MEM memId="m88" CLM01="4"></MEM>
            <MEM memId="m99" CLM01="5"></MEM>
            <MEM memId="m11" CLM01="5"></MEM>
        </CUS>
    </VEN>
</Data>
```

**Note**: Mixing children and siblings traversal. Tunneling parameters.